# VBA_How to end a For cycle in halfway and carry out the next one

Tags: excel, cycle, vba

Good morning,

I'm working on a quelity control report in EXCEL.
I've two tables, one is my table, the other is the original table. I'd like to go through the original one and search the key information and put it into the correct cell in my report table.
Here is my idea:

```
For each line i in my table

for each line j in the report table
    if it contains the main title and the correct zone
        for each cell k in this line j
            if there is my answer(like coulour:red)
                put it in my table
                [HERE I WANT TO QUIT THE FOR CYCLE OF k AND j AND GOTO NEXT i]
            end if
        next k
    end if
next j

next i
```

I've tried some methods like add a 'next j'but failed. It causes the bug. 
So if you've some idea please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this algorithm:

```
declare exit flag for j and set it to false

For each line i in my table

for each line j in the report table
    if it contains the main title and the correct zone
        for each cell k in this line j
            if there is my answer(like coulour:red)
                put it in my table
                set exit flag for j to true '<-- update
                exit for                    '<-- update
            end if
        next k
    end if
    if exit flag for j is true then set it to false and exit for '<-- update
next j

next i
```

Comment: Thank you, and how to declare a flag? just like 'Flag = True'?

Comment: `Dim flag as Boolean` then on the next line, `flag = False` or `flag = True`

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you very much. I just want to reduce some extra/useless process because it works a little bit slowly (I have about 20000 lines in my report). So I hope to release the burden.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to tell the j loop if the k loop exited because of the condition you set, the flag does that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  If you need to completely exit all of the loops, the only way i know of is to use a `do while` loop that increments the i and j values inside the loop.  Then, when you reach your desired condition, raise the values by one and use a GoTo statement to send the code back to the start of the loop.

However, since it seems that you only want to exit the K and J loops but remain inside the I, use the "Exit For" statement.  I think you may have to repeat the search condition somehow to exit the second loop after exiting the first, but using a boolean that is triggered by the first exit statement would make this easy enough

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a try, and tell you more details about that!